# Unable to Publish Source: API Request Timeout in Brownie while Publishing Source

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, contract-debugging, rinkeby

While working and deploying the FundMe.sol  Patric Collins tutorial on FreeCodeCamp. I stumbled upon the following error generated while trying to publish the source when using
**`FundMe.deploy({"from":account}, publish_source=True)`**. The error generated in **Brownie** is as follow's: `raise ValueError(f"API request failed with: {data['result']}") ValueError: API request failed with: []`. If anyone knows a solution to this issue it would be a great help.

What I have already tried:

- Running a test in order to debug.
- Trying to remove SafeMath (After reading **`get_verification_info`** inside **`--pdb`** led me to remove it.)
- Trying to verify the Rinkeby Etherscan API url via `curl`
- Rechecking my **.env**
- Trying to ask on Discord/Other Communities.
- Checking Github Pages/Google/StackOverflow/Eth-Stackoverflow for a solution.

Here is the source-code for **deploy.py**:

```
def deploy_fund_me():
    # Getting the account.
    account = get_account()
    # Deploying Contract with publish_source=True
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from":account}, publish_source=True)
    print(f"[Contract] Contract Deployed to {fund_me.address}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright! A Bit more Stumbling and I found a working solution. Turn's out I also need to add
the following to **brownie-config.yaml**. Brownie does not automatically use Infura and we need to manually add it to the networks. After adding the below code and running *deploy.py*  using, `brownie run ./scripts/deploy.py --network rinkeby`. The publishing is successful.

To fix the above error, Simply add the below code to your already existing (or create one) **brownie-config.yaml**, If you are working on other networks. Modify the below code accordingly.
\

```
live:
  - name: Ethereum
    networks:
      - name: Rinkeby (Infura)
        chainid: 4
        id: rinkeby
        host: https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
        explorer: https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api
```

Reference to the above solution can be found @ ["Common Pitfalls" by Matnad](https://matnad.medium.com/how-to-verify-your-brownie-project-on-etherscan-82d6086644cf)

Answer (score 0):

I use a .env file in my project folder with

```
export ETHERSCAN_TOKEN=xxxx
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=xxxx
```

then in the brownie-config.yaml all you have to do is add `dotenv: .env`
and publish_source=True will work.